# Storing disassembled data in a structured way

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x, reflection

I want to store the information returned by the dis function of the dis module in a structured way, using a dict, associating the mnemonics of each code of a line to the correspondent line number.

Note: `Instruction` is a subclass of `_Instruction`, defined in the `dis` module as a `namedtuple`.

**Output:**

```
disassembled_dict = 
{
 147: [ Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, arg1=0, arg2=0, argval='x', argrepr='x', offset=0, starts_line=147, is_jump_target=False),
        Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=1, arg1=1, arg2=0, argval=1, argrepr='1', offset=3, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), 
        Instruction(opname='INPLACE_ADD', opcode=55, arg=None, arg1=None, arg2=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=6, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), 
        Instruction(opname='STORE_FAST', opcode=125, arg=0, arg1=0, arg2=0, argval='x', argrepr='x', offset=7, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
      ] 

 148: [ Instruction(opname='LOAD_FAST', opcode=124, arg=0, arg1=0, arg2=0, argval='x', argrepr='x', offset=10, starts_line=148, is_jump_target=False),
        Instruction(opname='LOAD_CONST', opcode=100, arg=2, arg1=2, arg2=0, argval=2, argrepr='2', offset=13, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), 
        Instruction(opname='BINARY_POWER', opcode=19, arg=None, arg1=None, arg2=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=16, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False), 
        Instruction(opname='RETURN_VALUE', opcode=83, arg=None, arg1=None, arg2=None, argval=None, argrepr='', offset=17, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
      ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
import dis

def preatty_dis(function):
    fcode = function.__code__
    ## call dis._get_instructions_bytes just the original dis function do
    disassembled_raw = [instruction for instruction in
                        dis._get_instructions_bytes(fcode.co_code, fcode.co_varnames,
                                                    fcode.co_names, fcode.co_consts,
                                                    fcode.co_cellvars + fcode.co_freevars,
                                                    dict(dis.findlinestarts(fcode)))]
    iter_instructions = iter(disassembled_raw)
    disassembled_dict = {}
    line_pack = []
    while True:
        try:
            if not(line_pack):
                instruction = next(iter_instructions)
                line_pack.append(instruction)
            else:
                instruction = line_pack[0]

            if(instruction.starts_line):
                instruction = next(iter_instructions)
                while(instruction.starts_line is None):
                    line_pack.append(instruction)
                    instruction = next(iter_instructions)
                else:
                    ## line_pack[0] is the first mnemonic of the code line
                    ## line_pack[0].starts_line is the number of the code line
                    disassembled_dict.update({line_pack[0].starts_line : (line_pack)})
                    line_pack = [instruction]
            else:
                disassembled_dict.update({line_pack[0].starts_line : (line_pack)})
                line_pack = []
        except StopIteration:
            ## append the last group
            print(line_pack)
            disassembled_dict.update({line_pack[0].starts_line : (line_pack)})
            line_pack = []
            break
    return disassembled_dict
```

The code works on Python 3.5, but I'm sure there are many chances to make it more idiomatic, cleaner and more readable...

Suggestions?

Comment: I didn't understand a point he made, maybe you can clear it for me. He suggested to define a local function for `disassembled_dict.update({line_pack[0].starts_line : (line_pack)})`, but I think that is atomic, I can't split it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a superfluous use of a list comprehension: `[instruction for instruction in dis._get_instructions_bytes(…)]`.  You can just call `dis._get_instructions_bytes()` directly.

As indicated by the `_` prefix, `dis._get_instructions_bytes()` is an undocumented and unsupported method.  If you choose to write code that relies on undocumented behaviour, you have a duty to point it out with an obvious apologetic comment.

I'm not convinced that you need to use an undocumented function, though.  [`dis.get_instructions()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.get_instructions) seems to work just fine.

The use of `next()` to iterate through `disassembled_raw` is awkward, and I'm sure that is what prompted you to post this question.  Fundamentally, what you want to achieve is a "group by" operation, so you want to use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).  The only tricky thing is that you want `instruction.starts_line` being `None` to mean that that instruction should be lumped with the previous batch.  For that, you could use a hack: make the key function stateful.

You seem to have a stray `print()` call at the end, left over from debugging.

### Suggested solution

```
import dis
import itertools

def pretty_dis(function):
    last_seen_starts_line = None
    def stateful_starts_line(instruction):
        """Extract line number for the instruction, which is either
           instruction.starts_line if there is one, or the previously
           seen instruction.starts_line if there isn't."""
        nonlocal last_seen_starts_line
        last_seen_starts_line = instruction.starts_line or last_seen_starts_line
        return last_seen_starts_line

    return {
        line_num: list(instructions)
        for line_num, instructions in itertools.groupby(
            dis.get_instructions(function), key=stateful_starts_line
        )
    }
```

Comment: I've chosen `dis.get_instructions()` as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

- It should probably spell `pretty_dis`.
- Instead of `break`ing you can put the `return disassembled_dict` right
  there since that's the only thing you do after the loop anyway.
- A few of the parenthesis aren't needed, i.e. after `while`, `not` and
  around `line_pack`.
- The expression `disassembled_dict.update({line_pack[0].starts_line : (line_pack)})` appears three times -
  time to put that into a (local) function.  You could also fit in the
  `line_pack` reset with some thought.

Otherwise looks good IMO.

Comment: update is a built-in method of the dict type, right?

Comment: Yes, I meant the whole expression is repeated three times, so it should be extracted into a separate function.